# how to search a regular expression under path?

Tags: macos, unix

how to search a regular expression under path?
eg, I want to find all files which contain 'UPDATE player', under path /Users/Document/.

Comment: I think this question would be more topical for superuser.com. If enough other users agree with me it will be migrated there automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /Users/Document | xargs grep your_regex
```

Comment: I read that question as "files which contain", not files that are named.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -rl 'UPDATE player' /Users/Document/
```